# How do I get each textview resource amount and add them all together into a single variable to be converted into a two sliced pie chart?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

This is the code I have been working on for a while. The only issue is I cannot seem to be able to get the sum of values input into the editText fields that are dynamically added into the program and then place them into a pie chart. The data is to be transferred from the second activity to the third where the third activity will add up all resource amounts and display them into a pie chart.

**SecondActivity.class**

```
package com.example.a4mob;

import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.drawable.ColorDrawable;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.InputType;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.ActionBar;
import androidx.appcompat.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AlertDialog;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatSpinner;
import androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class SecondActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {
        public DrawerLayout drawerLayout;
        public ActionBarDrawerToggle actionBarDrawerToggle;

        private LinearLayout linearLayout;
        private Button add;
        //for button add resource
        List<String> ColourList = new ArrayList<>();
        ArrayList<Results> resultList = new ArrayList<>();

        private Button submit;
        private Number uinput;
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstance){
            super.onCreate(savedInstance);
            setContentView(R.layout.secondactivity);

            // drawer layout instance to toggle the menu icon to open
            // drawer and back button to close drawer
            drawerLayout = findViewById(R.id.my_drawer_layout);
            actionBarDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawerLayout, R.string.nav_open, R.string.nav_close);

            // pass the Open and Close toggle for the drawer layout listener
            // to toggle the button
            drawerLayout.addDrawerListener(actionBarDrawerToggle);
            actionBarDrawerToggle.syncState();

            // to make the Navigation drawer icon always appear on the action bar
            getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

            ActionBar actionBar;
            actionBar = getSupportActionBar();

            // Define ColorDrawable object and parse color
            // using parseColor method
            // with color hash code as its parameter
            ColorDrawable colorDrawable
                    = new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("grey"));

            // Set BackgroundDrawable
            actionBar.setBackgroundDrawable(colorDrawable);

            //Adds more objects

            linearLayout = findViewById(R.id.layout_list);
            add = findViewById(R.id.CreateNew);
            add.setOnClickListener(this);

            ColourList.add("grey");
            ColourList.add("green");
            ColourList.add("blue");
            ColourList.add("yellow");

            // Creating submit button click listener
            submit = findViewById(R.id.Submit);
            submit.setOnClickListener(this);

        }

        public void onClick(View view){
            switch (view.getId()){
                case R.id.CreateNew:
                    addView();
                    break;
                case R.id.Submit:
                    if(isValid()){
                            Intent intent = new Intent(SecondActivity.this, ThirdActivity.class);
                            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                            bundle.putSerializable("list", resultList);
                            intent.putExtras(bundle);
                            startActivity(intent);
                    }
                    break;
            }
        }

    private boolean isValid() {
            resultList.clear();
            boolean valid = true;

            for(int i = 0; i < linearLayout.getChildCount(); i++){
                View resultView = linearLayout.getChildAt(i);

                EditText resultName = (EditText) resultView.findViewById(R.id.RName);
                EditText resultNumber = (EditText) resultView.findViewById(R.id.RAmount);

                AppCompatSpinner COP = (AppCompatSpinner) resultView.findViewById(R.id.ColourOP);

                Results results = new Results();

                if(!resultName.getText().toString().equals("")){
                    results.setResName(resultName.getText().toString());
                }else{
                    valid = false;
                    break;
                }

                if(!resultNumber.getText().toString().equals("")){
                    results.setResAmount(Integer.parseInt(resultNumber.getText().toString()));
                }else{
                    valid = false;
                    break;
                }

                if(COP.getSelectedItemPosition()!=0){

                }else{
                    valid = false;
                    break;
                }

                resultList.add(results);

            }

            if(resultList.size() == 0){
                valid = false;
                Toast.makeText(this, "Complete all fields first", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else if(!valid){
                Toast.makeText(this, "Enter details correctly", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            return valid;
    }

    public void addAmount(){
        for(int i = 0; i < linearLayout.getChildCount(); i++) {
            View resultView = linearLayout.getChildAt(i);

            EditText resultNumber = (EditText) resultView.findViewById(R.id.RAmount);

            Results results = new Results();

        }
    }

    private void sub(){
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
            builder.setTitle("Please input inventory space:");

            // Set up the input
            final EditText input = new EditText(this);
            // Specify the type of input expected; this, for example, sets the input as a password, and will mask the text
            input.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER);
            builder.setView(input);

            // Set up the buttons
            builder.setPositiveButton("Continue", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    uinput = input.getInputType();
                    changeAct();
                }
            });
            builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    dialog.cancel();
                }
            });

            builder.show();
    }

        private void changeAct(){
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, ThirdActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }

        private void addView(){

            View newResource = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.row_add_data, null, false);

            ImageView imageClose = (ImageView)newResource.findViewById(R.id.Remove);
            TextView RN = (TextView) newResource.findViewById(R.id.RName);
            TextView RA = (TextView) newResource.findViewById(R.id.RAmount);
            AppCompatSpinner COP = (AppCompatSpinner) newResource.findViewById(R.id.ColourOP);

            ArrayAdapter arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, ColourList);
            COP.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);

            imageClose.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    removeView(newResource);
                }
            });

            linearLayout.addView(newResource);
        }

        private void removeView(View view){
                linearLayout.removeView(view);
        }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {

        if (actionBarDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @Override
    public void onPointerCaptureChanged(boolean hasCapture) {
        super.onPointerCaptureChanged(hasCapture);
    }
}
```

**ThirdActivity.class**

```
package com.example.a4mob;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.ActionBar;
import androidx.appcompat.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.drawable.ColorDrawable;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class ThirdActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    RecyclerView recycle_results;
    ArrayList<Results> resultList = new ArrayList<>();
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.thirdactivity);

        recycle_results = findViewById(R.id.res_results);

        LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this, RecyclerView.VERTICAL, false);
        recycle_results.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);

        resultList = (ArrayList<Results>) getIntent().getExtras().getSerializable("list");

        recycle_results.setAdapter(new ResultsAdapter(resultList));

    }
}
```

**Results.class**

```
package com.example.a4mob;

import java.io.Serializable;

public class Results implements Serializable {

    public String resourceName;
    public int resourceAmount;
    public int totalAmount;

    public Results(){

    }

    public int getTotalAmount() {
        return totalAmount;
    }

    public void setTotalAmount(int totalAmount) {
        this.totalAmount = totalAmount;
    }

    public int getResAmount() {
        return resourceAmount;
    }

    public void setResAmount(int resourceAmount) {
        this.resourceAmount = resourceAmount;
    }

    public Results(String resourceName, int resourceAmount){
        this.resourceName = resourceName;
        this.resourceAmount = resourceAmount;
    }

    public String getResName() {
        return resourceName;
    }

    public void setResName(String resourceName) {
        this.resourceName = resourceName;
    }

}
```

**ResultsAdapter.class**

```
package com.example.a4mob;

import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class ResultsAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ResultsAdapter.ResultsView> {

    ArrayList<Results> resultList = new ArrayList<>();
    int total;
    public ResultsAdapter(ArrayList<Results> resultList) {
        this.resultList = resultList;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ResultsView onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.row_results,parent,false);
        return new ResultsView(view);

    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ResultsView holder, int position) {
        Results results = resultList.get(position);
        holder.resourceName.setText(results.getResName());
        holder.resourceAmount.setText(String.valueOf(results.getResAmount()));
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return resultList.size();
    }

    public class ResultsView extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

        TextView resourceName, resourceAmount, resourceTotal;
        public ResultsView(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            resourceName = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.resNa);
            resourceAmount = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.resAm);

            resourceTotal = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.resTot);
        }
    }
}
```

**thirdactivity.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".ThirdActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/layoutThird"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/res_results"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"></androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView>

    </LinearLayout>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

**row_results.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/white"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
    app:cardCornerRadius="10dp"
    app:cardElevation="10dp">

    <LinearLayout
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:weightSum="1"
        android:layout_marginBottom="0dp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/resNa"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Resource Name"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:textColor="@color/black"></TextView>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/resAm"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Resource Amount"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:textColor="@color/black"></TextView>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/resTot"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Resource Amount"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:textColor="@color/black"></TextView>

    </LinearLayout>


</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```